# How come a program which is not Linux changes permissions for Linux?

Tags: permissions, drupal

I understood from [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/290604) that after `composer require` Drupal will harden file permissions.

How come a program which is not Linux (in this case, Composer, or Drupal) changes permissions for Linux?
Isn't permission change a task for a human user (from root or sudo account)?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "a program that is not Linux".  Any program that you run can issue any other command on your behalf. Shell scripts _rely_ on this fact.

Comment: I think I meant to a program which isn't a command or a shell script. Something written solely or primarily with PHP like Composer or Drupal.

Comment: Shell scripts aren't anything special. PHP is just another language running in another interpreter, having the same capabilities as any other piece of software.

Comment: Hmm? In what way is `composer require` not a command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Isn't permission change a task for a human user (from root or sudo account)?

No, and also, there's very sparsely any concept of "human" in computer software. Humans always interact through hardware and different software components. Nothing is "special" about chmod or sudo.